# barometer for loop adding in 3rd time

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

hi i have barometer MS5611 an i have problems to making an average number

for beginning i trying to making sum with 100 numbers but some how i get feed-beak wrong some how it add my answer only in the 3rd time

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      pression += barometer.getPressure(MS561101BA_OSR_4096);
      Serial.println(pression);
      delay(20);
```

my output

```
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
973.84
973.84
973.84
1947.69
1947.69
1947.69
2921.57
2921.57
2921.57
```

Comment: Are you sure this is C code? (it is possible but not probable)

Comment: Because the barometric pressure reading unit, does not collect data as fast as you can poll? Love the "feed-beak".

Comment: Weather Vane seems right. You get zero values until the measuring is done, then one correct value, which seems pretty constant. Reading it resets and you get another set of zeros. So it seems that you could poll (slower, probably) until you get non-zero. Then use that valid value in your calculation.

Comment: As Weather Vane alluded to, you appear to be polling faster than the barometer is updating.  Here is some sample code demonstrating the protocol for requesting data from these types of devices...
http://www.amsys.info/sheets/amsys.en.an520_e.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The code looks OK...  assuming that you are clearing the "pression" variable before entering the loop and we're looking at this:(http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data+Sheet%7FMS5611-01BA03%7FB2%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_MS5611-01BA03_B2.pdf%7FCAT-BLPS0036).  What's not shown is likely the problem.  I would take a step back and query the temperature sensor instead of the pressure.  Look into issuing a soft-reset to the device as part of your initialization, I expect you have a problem not here, but in your lower level code that's actually writing and reading bits from your SPI (or I2C) port.  Your delay should not be here, but it should be between the command to start conversion and the read of the data.  Watch the SDO line to see when the conversion is done, and have a 10 to 15ms backup timeout in case something goes wrong.  Make sure that the underlying code there is bulletproof, then worry about this upper level code.